# Salt cmd.run to NOT show the server name

Tags: linux, server, salt-stack

When running a command from a salt-master linux box I always get something similar to the following result:

```
[root@salt-master ~]# salt 'target-server' cmd.run 'date'
target-server:
    Fri Jul 24 22:41:44 UTC 2015
```

What can I do to get only the result of the command and NOT the targeted server too?

```
[root@salt-master ~]# salt 'target-server' cmd.run 'date' --SOMETHING I HAVE TO DO---
Fri Jul 24 22:41:44 UTC 2015
```

Comment: May I know why server name causes a problem? Normally it is possible to process output and remove it outside of Salt itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Salt's JSON output format together with the command line utility `jq` to extract the values you need. On CentOS you'll need to install the package `jq` to use it.

The command line

```
salt 'target-server' cmd.run 'date' --out json | jq -r '.[]'
```

will output

```
Sun Jul 26 15:17:40 UTC 2015
```

(the `-r` option prevents double quotes around the output).

[There are several other output formats available for Salt.](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/index.html)

Comment: When trying I get "-bash: jq: command not found" but I have flex bison libtool python installed. Any ideas?

Comment: you might need to `apt  install jq` as jq is not a default packages in many distributions